# How to integrate Azure App Insight into Node-Red?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, node-red

I want to collect some metrics from my Node-Red application using Azure App insight. I have already configured App functions and insight in Azure Resource Groups. I installed [this](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-azure-application-insights) library into my Node-Red application but I don't know how to use it and also I cannot find any guideline for that? Please let me know how can I properly integrate App insight into my Node-Red application? Thank you!

Comment: Add a new [function](https://i.imgur.com/34z6QzB.png) and add the code including Instrumentation or Connection string of AI.

Comment: `I have already configured App functions and insight in Azure Resource Groups.`, Can you please share the screenshot of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to add the code which includes `Instrumentation key` of Application Insights.
- You can directly add the key in the `settings.js` file, which is available in the `C:\Users\v****\.node-red` Installed node-red path.
- Define the function of  ApplicationInsights under  `Node Settings` => `functionGlobalContext`

```cs
functionGlobalContext: {
    //Configure AppInsights
},
```

I have taken references from [NodeJS SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs#sdk-configuration)

- But configuring in `settings.js` will effect all the applications.
- If you want to configure it for your specific node-red app, check the below workaround.
- Create a basic flow with `Inject` and `Debug`  nodes, connect Inject with Debug Node.
- And add a message by double clicking the Inject node => Deploy and check the output.

[image]

- Now add a new function node and include to configure Application Insights.
- Connect `Function` node with `Inject` and `Debug`.

[image]
[image]